# How to assert that a jQuery cluetip has been binded to something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, cluetip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery cluetip('destroy') does not destroy/remove cluetip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950197/jquery-cluetipdestroy-does-not-destroy-remove-cluetip)

In my code, there is a cluetip that binds itself to an anchor.  I need to know what sort of properties can I assert when unit testing it?

At the moment, all I could do is to assert the id of the cluetip, which seems insufficient.  I want to find out whether there is some sort of class in cluetip that changes when it is binded to a particular html element.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950197/jquery-cluetipdestroy-does-not-destroy-remove-cluetip) thread for answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've read the [ClueTip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/) code and it uses the `$(...).bind()` function to bind the desired method desired of showing the tip with the desired element.

I believe that any method of inspecting the bindings of an element will have the desired effect.

It uses the following bindings:

```
click.cluetip
focus.cluetip
blur.cluetip
mousemove.cluetip
mouseenter.cluetip
mouseleave.cluetip
```

depending of course the desired method.

Comment: @Paulo Santos: I believe the way cluetip works is that there is only ever 1 instance of cluetip. Whenever a html element needed to display a cluetip, it binds itself to it. So based on that thinking, when a cluetip is needed there has to be a change of certain variable in cluetip which tells it that okay now I'm displaying info for anchor A. I want to know whether such variable exists, and if so what is it and how to get to it. Being not from javascript background makes reading that file a nightmare. And no I can only use jQuery or Javascript, cant use other 3rd party software. Thanks.